# How to view a user's status (online, absent, offline)?

Tags: php, drupal, twig, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I want to get the status of the user on Drupal 8.

With the code below, if the user is online, the status is online. But if the user has been offline for more than an hour, the status is missing. Normally it should be offline.

What's wrong with this code ?

Thank you

Here is what I added in the `user.html.twig` file :

```
<div class="bs-field-status">
  {% if status == 'Online' %}
    <i class="user-online fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Online
  {% elseif status == 'Absent' %}
    <i class="user-absent fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Absent
  {% else %}
    <i class="user-offline fa fa-circle fa-lg"></i> Offline
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

`bootstrap_sub.theme` :

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Bootstrap sub-theme.
 *
 * Place your custom PHP code in this file.
 */

use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_presave().
 */
function bootstrap_sub_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  // get user object
  $user = $variables['elements']['#user'];
  //- The user has logged in at least once
  if ($user->getLastLoginTime()) {
    if (account_is_logged_in_less_then_thirty_minutes($user->id())) {
      $status = 'Online';
    }
    else {
      $status = 'Absent';
    }
  }
  else {
    $status = 'Offline';
  }
  $variables['status'] = $status;
}

/**
 * @param $uid
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function account_is_logged_in_less_then_thirty_minutes($uid) {
  $connection = Database::getConnection();
  $query = $connection->select('sessions', 'sessions')
    ->fields('sessions', ['sid', 'uid', 'timestamp'])
    ->condition('sessions.uid', $uid, '=')
    //- chef if the user was online in 30 minutes (60 * 30)
    ->condition('sessions.timestamp', \Drupal::time()
        ->getRequestTime() - (60 * 30), '>')
    ->execute();
  //- Get result.
  $results = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  return (count($results) > 0) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, There is no built in functionality for this (and I cant find a module that does it), so you are going to have to create your own module. Your module could probably query the session table of the database to get the information you need.

Comment: @2pha I updated my question

Comment: You should write an alert box/auto refresh on 5/10 minutes and save the session time in table. You will want to compare the timings and can display accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, You dont have to involve in the session. As Drupal User Object provides getLastAccessedTime() method which can do the trick for you.

```
  $userLastAccessTime = $user->getLastAccessedTime();
  $unixTime20MinBeforeNow = strtotime("-20 Minutes");
  $unixTime1HourBeforeNow = strtotime("-1 Hours");
  /*
   * User last access time is more than last 10 minutes.
   * User was actve withing last 30 minutes.
   */
  if ($userLastAccessTime > $unixTime20MinBeforeNow) {
    $status = 'Online';
  } else if ($userLastAccessTime > $unixTime1HourBeforeNow) {
    $status = 'Absent';
  } else {
    $status = 'Offline';
  }
```